# Swift3 downloading JSON data with Alamofire and return dictionary

Tags: swift3

I am pretty new to Swift, (rookie), have good experience with C# though.

What I am trying to do is use Alamofire to dowload JSON data from an API and return a dictionary back to the calling method. 
I am having issues with the function not returning back the data to the calling function. I am assuming that my issue is that the download is asynchronous.

Here is my code of the function that is to download the data.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class SharedFunctions {


   class func downloadWeatherData(url: String, completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) ->  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {


        let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: url)!

        var workingDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? = nil

        Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseJSON {
            response in
            let result = response.result

            workingDict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            completed()

        }

        return workingDict

    }
}
```

I have this type alias stored in a separate constants class.

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

My calling function, when it hits the if let dict, the code will continue on without doing much. This function is being called from the view controller code.

```
 func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete)
 { 
        if let dict = SharedFunctions.downloadWeatherData(url: CURRENTWEATHERURL, completed: completed) {

            if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
                self._cityName = name.capitalized
           }

        }
  completed()
 }
```

My old code that was working, I had the call to Alamofire being called from the downloadWeatherDetails function and had it working fine, data was returning back to the VC when the download was complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes in your function like this way -

```
    typealias DownloadComplete = Dictionary<String, Any>

    func downloadWeatherData(url: String, completion: (DownloadComplete) -> Void) {

        //Do your process here  
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {
        response in
          // Finish process here
           switch response.result {
           case .success:
            completion(response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>) 
            case .failure(let error):
            completion([:])
            print(error)
           }

        } 

    }

    //MARK: - Call function
    downloadWeatherData(url: "your url here") { (DownloadComplete) in
        //Do something with data 
        print(DownloadComplete)
    }
```

Comment: response.result.value not have value property in latest Alomafire

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1. The `downloadWeatherData` is trying to return data that is returned asynchronously. It shouldn't return anything, but rather just pass the data back in the closure.
2. The `downloadWeatherDetails` has a confusing combination of taking a closure parameter, passing it directly to `downloadWeatherData`, but also (a) trying to supply its own closure to that method; and (b) updating a property, too.

   It should probably just build some model object, and, again, pass that back via a closure. It also should not update a property, either.

So, let's step back. To pass the dictionary results back, update the closure's `typealias` accordingly:

```
typealias DownloadComplete = ([String: Any]?) -> Void
```

As an aside, I use the `[KeyType: ValueType]` syntax, which is more concise than `Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>`, but you can use that other syntax if you really want. Also note that I make that parameter of the closure optional (so you can differentiate between a successful call and a failure).

And then `downloadWeatherData` is simply:

```
/// Return the dictionary returned by web service.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - url:       URL of the web service.
///   - completed: The closure that's called when the asynchronous call finishes. If there was an error, the dictionary will be `nil`.
class func downloadWeatherData(url: String, completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in
        completed(response.result.value as? [String: Any])
    }
}
```

The intent of your other method, `downloadWeatherDetails`, is less clear. You appear to be attempting to both update some property as well as call a closure. Just to keep things clean, I'd suggest you do one or the other, but not both.

For example, I could imagine some model object:

```
struct WeatherReport {
    let city: String
    let low: Float
    let high: Float
}
```

And `downloadWeatherDetails` could extracted some key pieces of information, perhaps building that model object (I've renamed the method, accordingly):

```
/// Build `WeatherReport` object and pass it back in the closure.
///
/// - Parameter completed: The closure that will be called when the method finishes.

func downloadWeatherReport(completed: @escaping (WeatherReport?) -> Void) {
    SharedFunctions.downloadWeatherData(url: currentWeatherUrl) { dictionary in
        guard let city = dictionary?["name"] as? String, let low = dictionary?["low"] as? Float, let high = dictionary?["high"] as? Float else {
            completed(nil)
            return
        }
        
        completed(WeatherReport(city: city, low: low, high: high))
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know if that model object captures everything you want. Likewise, I don't know what the keys are to your dictionary. But it illustrates the idea: Extract the information you need to build a model object, and pass that back via the closure (not a `return` statement).

Anyway, continuing with my theoretical example, I could then do something like this, which updates the UI, perhaps invoked in `viewDidLoad` or on the tap of a button:

```
downloadWeatherReport { weatherReport in
    guard let weatherReport = weatherReport else {
        // handle error here
        return
    }

    // update some model property

    self.weatherReport = weatherReport

    // and update the UI, too

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    self.cityLabel.text = weatherReport.city
    self.lowLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: weatherReport.low))
    self.highLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: weatherReport.high))
}
```

But don't get lost in the details of my example, but rather focus on the take home message that when dealing with asynchronous methods, don't try to immediately return data nor update properties, but rather pass data back via closures. And let the ultimate caller take care of updating the model and UI.